# How to compress whitespace in a List<string>?

Tags: c#, list, removing-whitespace

I am trying to compress all of the white-space in a C# List with the following code, but it won't compile...I get the red "Error" line under the whole `Regex` expression and I don't understand why.  Can anyone help me out here?

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ',', ':', '|', '\n' };
List<string> sortBox1 = new List<string>(textBox2.Text.Split(delimiterChars));

#region >> COMPRESS WHITESPACE
if (checkBox2.Checked)
{
    sortBox1 = Regex.Replace(sortBox1, @"\s+", " ").Trim();              
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Replace` method works on a single string, not a list of strings. You would loop through the strings in the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sortBox1.Count; i++) {
  sortBox1[i] = Regex.Replace(sortBox1[i], @"\s+", " ").Trim();
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Guffa.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
if (checkBox2.Checked)
{
    sortBox1 = sortBox1.Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ").Trim()).ToList();             
}
```

The error you are receiving will most likely be because you are passing `sortBox1` into the `Replace` method - it needs to be a `string` not a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String.Trim function

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ',', ':', '|', '\n' };
List<string> sortBox1 = new List<string>(checkBox2.Checked ? textBox2.Text.Split(delimiterChars).Select(s => s.Trim()) : textBox2.Text.Split(delimiterChars));
```